# Installing MathGL on OSX mavericks is causing linking errors

Tags: c++, osx-mavericks, mathgl

Hi I've been having a lot of trouble trying to build and install MathGL after upgrading to OS X Mavericks. Downloading the source and afterrunning CMake followed by make I get the following linker error:

```
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/mgl.dir/opengl.cpp.o
cd /Users/Maki/Desktop/mathgl-2x/src && /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/bin/gcc-4.8   
-Dmgl_EXPORTS - DNO_COLOR_ARRAY -DMGL_SRC -fopenmp -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC
-I/Users/Maki/Desktop/mathgl-2x/include -I/Users/Maki/Desktop/mathgl-2x/src/prc 
-I/usr/local/include -o CMakeFiles/mgl.dir/opengl.cpp.o -c /Users/Maki/Desktop/mathgl-2x/src/opengl.cpp
Linking CXX shared library libmgl.dylib
```

after pages of output ....

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/libmgl.7.1.0.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/mgl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help in getting this installed will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any error above. That's looks like normal output from make.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about adding compiler highlighting. But the very last line is the error. After that make dumps pages of output and fails to build